# Python : funcion 'end' se me aplica fuera de su entorno

Tags: python

Estoy aprendiendo Python, y haciendo unos ejercicios me encontre con el siguiente problema:

```
#bucle continue


for i in 'tonteria':

  if i == 't':

    continue
  
  print (i, end= ' ')
  

#un ejemplo practico de esto es el de contar letras sin contar los espacios, por ejemplo:

variable = 'Esta frase tiene 22 letras'

contador = 0

for i in variable :

  if i == ' ':
    continue
  contador = contador + 1  

print (contador)
```

Mi problema es que me imprime : 'o n e r i a 22 ' o sea todo en un mismo renglon cuando segun lo que yo entiendo esa instruccion 'end' no deberia salir del entorno en el que se está ejecutando, es decir que yo esperaria que me imprima oneria y 22 en renglones distintos

No entiendo la logica que está interpretando python para hacerlo de esa manera.

PD: ya se como se hace para dejar ese espacio, pero como dije, lo que me importa es entender la logica que aplica python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estas recorriendo la palabra letra a letra, y haces el `print()` en cada iteración, por lo tanto te coloca el espacio detrás de cada letra.

Para lo que quieres no te hace falta recorrer la palabra letra a letra sino llamar directamente al `print()`:

```
print('tonteria', end=' ')
```

Otra cosa seria si tienes una lista con muchos `strings`:

```
list = ['asdasd', 'caqwe', 'prtdf']

for i in list:
    print(i, end=' ')
```

Esto te imprimiria: `asdasd caqwe prtdf`

EDIT:

Por cierto, lo que dices de renglón no sé si te refieres al salto de línea, si dejas el `end` por defecto, o sea sin ponerlo, hace el salto de línea, si le pasas un valor ya no te lo hace y sólo hace lo que le pasaste.

Comment: Buenos dias, ya lo se y fue a drede para practicar el end, mi dificultad no es esa sino entender porque el 'end' se me esta aplicando tambien en el siguiente for , (al poner 22 en el mismo renglon que 'oneria'

Comment: Lee lo que acabo de editar en mi respuesta.

Comment: Hmmm creo estar entendiendo que al yo hacer end='  '  estoy de hecho reasignandole un valor  la variable end´, y por eso de ahí en más cada salto de linea será ínterpretado como un espacio. La pregunta ahora seria como hacer para end vuelva a ser salto de linea. Ya probe con agregar una linea end= '/n' pero eso no es correcto y

Comment: La siguiente vez que llames al `print()` éste cogerá otra vez el salto de linea (`'\n'`), pero como lo pone al final, el 22 aun te sale en la misma linea, lo siguiente ya si que saldría abajo

Comment: Gracias,! efectivamente era asi. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Para lograr el resultado que esperas es necesario que imprimas un salto de linea luego del primer ciclo `for`, de esta manera:

```py
for i in 'tonteria':

  if i == 't':

    continue
  
  print (i, end= ' ')

print()
```

El parámetro `end` de la función `print()` establece la cadena que debe agregarse cuando finalice la impresión. De forma predeterminada, se establece con el carácter de nueva línea `\n`. Entonces, después de terminar de imprimir todas las variables, se agrega un carácter de nueva línea. Por lo tanto, obtenemos el resultado de cada declaración de impresión en una línea diferente.

Al cambiar el valor predeterminado del parámetro a un espacio en blanco `end=' '` la cadena que se agrega al final de la impresión es pues precisamente un espacio en blanco, es por eso que obtienes como resultado `o n e r i a 22`

Es importante tener en cuenta lo siguiente:

- `end` no es una función como se menciona en el título de la pregunta, es un parámetro de la función `print()`
- el ámbito de `end` no es el ciclo, sino el cuerpo de la función `print()`

Comment: Gracias! tu respesta tambien me fue muy util